# CSS href on database mysql through PHP

Tags: php, css, href

A noob question, :)
I will create a number of css and I would like the css href to be on the database .
so that when a specific user will log in, the href tag on the database will be called by PHP and load.

```
<link href="styles/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Is it possible? for example:

```
mysqli database
username : Admin cssstyle : admin.css
username : John  cssstyle : user.css
```

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $result['username']='Admin';
if($result['username']=='Admin')
$cssPath='styles/admin.css';
else
$cssPath='styles/user.css';
?>
<link href="<?php echo $cssPath;?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

> where the $result is database result array obtain from database